# How do i get the xprop output for my current window via ssh?

Tags: ssh, x11

On my device A, i'm running x11 with dwm. I want to ssh into device A from device B and get the xprop output for the window i've focused on the device A. When I'm in the terminal on device a in dwm, execute `xprop -id "$(xdotool getactivewindow)"` in my terminal emulator, I get the xprop output of my terminal emulator. However, when I execute this command via ssh i get this output:

```
Error: DISPLAY environment variable is empty. Is there an Xorg or other X server running? You can try setting 'export DISPLAY=:0' and trying again.
Failed creating new xdo instance.
xprop:  unable to open display ''
```

When i do `export DISPLAY=:0` (:0 is the value of $DISPLAY when i check it in the terminal emulator on device A), the above command produces the fowllowing error:

```
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
Failed creating new xdo instance.
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
xprop:  unable to open display ':0'
```

How do i fix this (specify an authorization protocol or whatever is neccessary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your distro does X authorization, and I am not familiar with `dwm`. One way is to store a "MIT magic cookie" in `~/.Xauthority`. You can modify it with `xauth`, see `man xauth`.

If you do something like `ps axu | grep X`, you will see the commandline of the X server, and on my distro, this includes an option `-auth /name/to/authfile`. I can copy this file directly to `~/.Xauthority` (that requires read permissions e.g. vs `sudo`), and I can thus authorize other users or ssh connections.

This may or may not work on your distro.

(You'll also get the advice to do `xhost +`, this is more insecure than to get a correct cookie).

Comment: If you didn’t have `xauth` before you were logging in with dwm, there’s no way it was using it in your dwm session.

Comment: this worked after rebooting on both machines.